# Eliminar un elemento de un Array en localStorage

Tags: javascript, array, json, local-storage

Estoy intentando eliminar un elemento de un array que se aloja en localStorage, para ello intento guardar el contenido de localStorage en una variable, parsearla, eliminar el elemento con splice y con idexOf, volver a parsearla y sobreescribir el localStorage pero me salta el siguiente error de JSON:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
> at JSON.parse ()

El código que tengo actualmente es el siguiente:

```
function eliminar(nombre){ //función que se ejecuta onclick con un botón y pasa por parámetro el 
                          // elemento del array del localStorage que quiero eliminar.

                  var localstorage=localStorage.getItem("usuario");
                  var arraystorage=JSON.parse(localstorage);
                  arraystorage.splice(arraystorage.indexOf(nombre),1) 
                  localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(arraystorage))  


                 }
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo que haces mal es no depurar la variable que te devuelve el método `getItem` del `localStorage`. Si la misma no es una cadena en formato JSON, entonces `JSON.parse` fallará al analizar la misma, que es precisamente lo que está pasando. Haz `console.log`de la variable `localstorage` para que visualices su contenido. Saludos

Comment: Diría que tienes dos errores tipográficos aquí:  `var araystorage=JSON.parse(localStorage);` pues creo que querias hacer esto en su lugar: `var arraystorage=JSON.parse(localstorage);`  (date cuenta de la S mayúscula y minúscula de localStorage ademas del nombre de la variable)

Comment: console.log de la variable localStorage me devuelve un String de los elementos separados con comas. Cómo lo depuro entonces? o qué opciones tengo? Gracias! @MauricioContreras

Comment: Gracias, han sido errores de transcripción, al ejecutar el error es el comentado en la pregunta. @masterguru

Comment: ok, bueno, si te devuelve un string separado por comas es que en alguna parte lo pusistes así y no como json u objeto. Busca en todo tu código `localStorage.setItem("usuario"` a ver como lo hicistes y donde, para saber como tratarlo y que no vuelva a suceder por otro lado después.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero un array de ejemplo

```
let array = [
        {
            hola : "jeje"
        },
        {
            hola: "jojo"
        }
```

luego agregamos esto a localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("usuario",JSON.stringify(array))
```

y para eliminarlo o editarlo o lo que quieras

```
    var localstorage=localStorage.getItem("usuario")
    console.log(JSON.parse(localstorage)) //json en consola
                  
    var araystorage=JSON.parse(localstorage)
    console.log(araystorage[0].hola) // resultado string "jeje"
    //elimina, edita, o lo que quieras, cambia 'hola' por un parametro de la funcion
    araystorage[0].hola = "eliminar" 
    console.log(araystorage) //recuerda borrar el console log
    localStorage.setItem("usuario",JSON.stringify(araystorage))
```

[image: resultados del console.log]

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la contestación, una pregunta tú sustituyes el valor del indice del array 0, pero se podría eliminar directamente para que el array pase a tener solo 1 elemento?